# How to add an export button in a razor view to export data into excel

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm implementing an asp.net core 3.0 project. I want in my razor view to have an export button then by clicking it, an excel sheet containing the razor view information downloads in a specified directory. For creating the export method, I thought it would be better to use EEPLUS and by using the link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-data-to-excel-file-in-asp-net-using-epplus/ I tried to export my razor view data into excel. But 
in that link, it says to add the below line to aspx page to have the export button, however, I want a button for razor view. I appreciate if anyone can tell me how to modify this instruction to be in the format of razor view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo about how to export data by using asp.net core:

1.download EPPLUS package on Nuget:
[image]

2.Razor View(Index.cshtml):

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" asp-action="Export" value="Export" />
</form>
```

3.Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Export()
    {
        var students = new[]
        {
            new {
                Id = "101", Name = "Vivek", Address = "Hyderabad"
            },
            new {
                Id = "102", Name = "Ranjeet", Address = "Hyderabad"
            },
            new {
                Id = "103", Name = "Sharath", Address = "Hyderabad"
            },
            new {
                Id = "104", Name = "Ganesh", Address = "Hyderabad"
            },
            new {
                Id = "105", Name = "Gajanan", Address = "Hyderabad"
            },
            new {
                Id = "106", Name = "Ashish", Address = "Hyderabad"
            }
        };

        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            workSheet.TabColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            workSheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;
            workSheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(students, true);
            package.Save();
        }
        stream.Position = 0;
        string excelName = "studentsRecord.xlsx"; 
        return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", excelName);
    }
}
```

If you want to show the same result to add a new column which is not in `students`,use the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Export()
{
    var students = ...;

    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        workSheet.TabColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        workSheet.DefaultRowHeight = 12;

        //workSheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(students, true);

        //Header of table  
        //  
        workSheet.Row(1).Height = 20;
        workSheet.Row(1).Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        workSheet.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;
        workSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "S.No";
        workSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Id";
        workSheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Name";
        workSheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Address";
        //Body of table  
        //  
        int recordIndex = 2;
        foreach (var student in students)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 1].Value = (recordIndex - 1).ToString();
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 2].Value = student.Id;
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 3].Value = student.Name;
            workSheet.Cells[recordIndex, 4].Value = student.Address;
            recordIndex++;
        }
        workSheet.Column(1).AutoFit();
        workSheet.Column(2).AutoFit();
        workSheet.Column(3).AutoFit();
        workSheet.Column(4).AutoFit();
        package.Save();
    }
    stream.Position = 0;
    string excelName = "studentsRecord.xlsx"; 
    return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", excelName);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to export to excel from the razor view.
Is it the entire view, an extract from the view, maybe a table in the view?

In you are using ASP.Net Core MVC: Pass the content you want to extract to the controller that will handle the button.

You will have to create a method that will do the following

1. Create the file for the content you want to be exported
2. Create sheet in the file
3. Create Rows and Columns and insert content passed into it
4. Split the content you passed as argument into the column content for multiple rows.
5. Insert split content into the file created and save it

Attach the method to the controller handling the button and redirect to the location of the file on your server as the return action.