# Large Data Download Using XLWorkbook in C# but Memory Issue

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am looking for a solution to download large data in Excel using C#.

I am using **XLWorkbook** library but memory issue I have 100M data so local memory full and performance slow in my system.

Are there any alternative method for **MemoryStream**?

**My code**

```
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(Global.Data, "Sheet1");

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            // Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + DateTime.Now + ".csv");
            Response.ContentType = "application/text";
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is application/text really correct contentype for an excel workbook

Comment: @siggemannen yes its a .csv file

Comment: Hi @GenishParvadia, have you considered trying the EPPLUS? Refer to this answer for [how to use EPPLUS in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60942866/11398810).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a MemoryStream, you can write the data directly to a file on the server. This approach can reduce memory usage significantly:

```
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    wb.Worksheets.Add(Global.Data, "Sheet1");

    // Directly write to a file
    string fileName = Path.Combine(tempPath, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".xlsx");
    wb.SaveAs(filename);

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFifilenameileName));
    Response.TransmitFile(fileName);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

And I Recommend using **EPPlus** Compared to **ClosedXML**

Comment: working nice but after 1M record error 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'

Comment: Try Not to Load the whole Data Into Memory Instead Divide your data Into Chunks